# Select node based on attribute and change subnode

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programmedata>
<programme id="1">
<name>Left</name>
<image_path></image_path>
<rating_point>0</rating_point>
<five_star>0</five_star>
```

With following code I am trying to edit value of rating_point:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("content.xml");
if(!empty($_POST["rating"]) && !empty($_POST["voted_programme"])){
    try{
     $rating = $_POST["rating"];
        $i = $_POST['voted_programme'];
        $xml->programme[$i]->rating_point = $rating;
        if($rating == '5')
        {
            $xml->programme[$i]->five_star = $rating;
        }
```

but getting error:
`Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of SimpleXMLElement has no effect in ...`

tried different solution but seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement `$xml->programme[1]->rating_point` **does not** select the `<programme>` node with the attribute `id="1"`.
It refers to the 2nd `<programme>` node in your XML, regardless of its `id` attribute.

There are basically 2 ways to get to `<programme id="1">`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$rating = 5;
$id = 1;
```

**#1 looping the entire XML**

```
foreach ($xml->programme as $item) {

    if ($item[`id`] == $id) { 

        $item->rating_point = $rating;
        if ($rating == 5) $item->five_star = $rating;
    }
}
```

Comment: see line 2 (`if...`) on how to access attributes.
see it working: https://eval.in/458300

**#2 select with `xpath`:**

```
$item = $xml->xpath("//programme[@id='$id']")[0];

if (!is_null($item)) {
    $item->rating_point = $rating;
    if ($rating == 5) $item->five_star = $rating;
}
```

Comments:

- `//programme`: select every `<programme>` node, wherever in the XML tree
- `[@id='1']`: a condition, `@` is for attribute
- the `xpath` function returns an array of `SimpleXML` elements, with the `[0]` we grab the first element in that array and put it into `$item`.

see it working: https://eval.in/458310

As you can see, solution #2 is faster, even more so if your XML contains several `<programme>` nodes.