# PHP Search and replace XML

Tags: php, xml, preg-replace

I have this XML code and i want to search and replace with PHPin tag PRICE i want to remove point and the result to be 9600,00.

Any idea ?

```
<AUCTION>
<UNIQUEID>36048</UNIQUEID>
<TITLE>UPS APC SMartUPS 20kVA SUVT20KH4B4S</TITLE>
<DESCRIPTION>UPS-uri &amp; Stabilizatoare &gt; UPS-uri ReconditionateUPS APC SMartUPS 20kVA SUVT20KH4B4SPretul afisat este fara BateriiAn de fabricatie 2006Functioneaza cu 128 acumulatori de 12V 7AEste inclus in pret modulul de bypassAPC Smart-UPS VT SUVT20KH4B4S 20 kVAInput400V 3PH / Output400V 3PH Interface Port DB-9 RS-232, Smart-Slot Extended runtime model.. Model : cu managment   Dimensiuni : 1499 x 559 x 813 mm, Greutate : 600 Kg, Putere : 20000 Va</DESCRIPTION>
<PRICE>9.600,00</PRICE>
<CURRENCY>RON</CURRENCY>

<CATEGORY>UPS-uri &amp; Stabilizatoare &gt; UPS-uri Reconditionate</CATEGORY>


<AMOUNT>0</AMOUNT>
<PHOTOS><URL>https://shoplaptop.ro/image/data/poze_VM/20130709_154155_51DCA400_5377F800.jpg</URL></PHOTOS>
<WARRANTY>1</WARRANTY>
<STATE>2</STATE>
</AUCTION>
```

Comment: Do you keeping it in a file or string ?

Comment: The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) are a great place to start.

Comment: I save the XML in my server.

Comment: `DomDocument` to access/manipulate the XML : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php and `number_format()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php or the `NumberFormatter` class : http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Have any ideea can i use function like ...$data = str_replace("</CATEGORY1>","</CATEGORY>", $data); ??

Comment: Yes... but string manipulation with XML is *usually* a bad idea so I'm not touching that, even with a long pointy stick.

Comment: as this is very simple and basic XML, you can do it with regex, like `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: Bobot, can you give me example ?

Comment: @Bobot don't do it man, it's not worth it ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: see this and work from there http://stackoverflow.com/a/33387211/2016456

Comment: @CD001 for what he wants to do it's just perfect, a limited set of xml, without traps.

Comment: @Bobot ... as far as you can see from this very limited sample set ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$xml_data->PRICE = str_replace('.', '', $xml_data->PRICE);
```

**OR**

```
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$xml_data = json_decode(json_encode($xml_data), true);
$xml_data['PRICE'] = str_replace('.', '', $xml_data['PRICE']);
```

The following code would work if you have more than one `AUCTION` tag:

```
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$xml_data = json_decode(json_encode($xml_data), true);
foreach($xml_data as &$xml_data_value) {
    $xml_data_value['PRICE'] = str_replace('.', '', $xml_data_value['PRICE']);
}
```

It works.

Comment: Can you give me full example of this code ? Ware save sa modified file ?

Comment: Can you explain how you want to work with this code? Do you have an individual XML file containing the tags that you've given in the question?

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/80af/bintekMarius.xml Here is the xml

Comment: What do you want to do with this file in PHP?

Answer (score -2):

A simple example to do this is using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

Consider `$str` containing your XML:

```
$str = <<<S
<AUCTION>
<UNIQUEID>36048</UNIQUEID>
<TITLE>UPS APC SMartUPS 20kVA SUVT20KH4B4S</TITLE>
<DESCRIPTION>UPS-uri &amp; Stabilizatoare &gt; UPS-uri ReconditionateUPS APC SMartUPS 20kVA SUVT20KH4B4SPretul afisat este fara BateriiAn de fabricatie 2006Functioneaza cu 128 acumulatori de 12V 7AEste inclus in pret modulul de bypassAPC Smart-UPS VT SUVT20KH4B4S 20 kVAInput400V 3PH / Output400V 3PH Interface Port DB-9 RS-232, Smart-Slot Extended runtime model.. Model : cu managment   Dimensiuni : 1499 x 559 x 813 mm, Greutate : 600 Kg, Putere : 20000 Va</DESCRIPTION>
<PRICE>9.600,00</PRICE>
<CURRENCY>RON</CURRENCY>

<CATEGORY>UPS-uri &amp; Stabilizatoare &gt; UPS-uri Reconditionate</CATEGORY>


<AMOUNT>0</AMOUNT>
<PHOTOS><URL>https://shoplaptop.ro/image/data/poze_VM/20130709_154155_51DCA400_5377F800.jpg</URL></PHOTOS>
<WARRANTY>1</WARRANTY>
<STATE>2</STATE>
</AUCTION>
S;

$str = preg_replace_callback('@<(price)>(.*?)</\1>@im', function($res) {
    return str_replace('.', '', $res[0]);
}, $str);

echo $str;
```